# Add column to DataFrame in rpy2

Tags: python, r, rpy2

I'm using R in python with rpy2. I have a dataframe with some columns in it and I want to add additional one.

As far as I understand I, in R I would write something like this:

```
df$new_colname <- cumsum(df$oldcolname)
```

But how can I translate this to rpy2?

I tried many variations of this:

```
ipdb> d.rx2('cum_misses') <- ro.r.cumsum(d.rx2('misses'))
*** Newest frame
```

But always get this:

```
ipdb> p d.rx2('cum_misses')
rpy2.rinterface.NULL
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I found the answer.

To add a column I have to write following code:

```
d = ro.r.cbind(d, cum_misses=ro.r.cumsum(d.rx2('misses')))
```

Answer (score 0):

To get an equivalent of `$` assignment use it directly as a three-argument function. First import the base package:

```
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr

base = importr('base')
set_column = getattr(base, '$<-')
```

Then to acheive the equivalent of:

```
df$new_colname <- value
```

Use:

```py
df = set_column(df, 'new_colname', value)
```